# cygwin sshd spinning a full CPU core after suspend/resume (windows 10)

Tags: cygwin, sshd

I've noticed within the past month or maybe two that whenever I resume my laptop from sleep, the sshd.exe cygwin process consumes 100% of a CPU core  (i.e. it reports constant "25%" utilization on my 4-core machine.

I *think* but cannot confirm that this started with one of the major feature updates to Windows 10 that I installed recently.

The problem can be temporarily resolved by doing a `HUP` on the sshd process, but as soon as I suspend/resume it starts spinning again, which substantially increases power and rips through the battery on the machine (not to mention it gets hot as hell)..

suggestions on what to do here?  I can't know at this point whether windows is the victim and cygwin/SSHD is the killer, or the other way around...

Versions:
Windows 10 Pro 20H2 build 19042.1052
OpenSSH_8.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

Comment: I had a similar issue since a month now. The main sshd spawns a dozen child sshd, making Windows unusable. I set up a cronjob which check child sshd every 10 minutes and kill them. I have not found root cause, maybe having something to do with antivirus.

Comment: have you checked if having also `cygserver` as service has any effect ?